# PHP myadmin import database failure

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin, joomla2.5

I am trying to import my old database back into phpmyadmin after deleting it and creating a new one...steps taken....deleted database after back up....created new database with different name and received this error when trying to import

> 1044 - Access denied for user 'augr_2'@'%' to database 'augr_2'

After some research i found that i must change my CREATE DATABASE line in my database .sql file after amendment it looked like this

```
CREATE DATABASE `augr_2` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
USE `augr_2`;
```

But i still keep getting this error?

this is the full error i receive

SQL query:

```
--
-- Database: `augr_2`
--
CREATE DATABASE  `augr_2` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

MySQL said:

> 1044 - Access denied for user 'augr_2'@'%' to database 'augr_2'

Comment: Have you read the error message? You are just missing the rights to access your new database. You should set those as well.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the mysql used by the PMA doesn't have rights on the newly created db , which is normal.

**Try this logged it as** ***root***

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'augr_2'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Comment: Hi Stephantried that and it returned SQL query:

GRANT ALL ON * . * TO  'augr_2'@'%';


MySQL said: 

#1045 - Access denied for user 'augr_2'@'%' (using password: YES)